# Aligning absolute positioned elements with backgrounds

Tags: html, css

if you have a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5TJ6G/3/ - And you resize your browser, you can get the X in the center of the background image. However, it doesn't stay there when you resize.

Is it possible to get it to stay in posistion without using fixed widths or position fixed? I suspect a little css trickery might have to be in order...

```
body {
        background: url('http://cl.ly/image/3j2s1u2n0t15/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-23%20at%2012.25.02.png') top center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .thing {
        position: absolute;
        top: 45%;
        left: 45%;
    }
```

To see an example in context: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/debug/gAByF - The white line things need to stay in relatively the same position.

Cheers.

Comment: You JSfiddle does not match your question code...you have an extra div.

Comment: Sorted. Was easier to apply it the the body :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
body {
    background: url('http://cl.ly/image/3j2s1u2n0t15/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-23%20at%2012.25.02.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.thing{
    position:absolute;
    top:49%;
    left:49%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img">
   <div class="thing">x</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TJ6G/5/

Comment: Ah you've cracked it haven't you. Though that works in such a simple scenario (which I asked and you then answered correctly, btw) I can't get it to work as well on the actual piece, the pen. Will look more in to it though. Now it's figuring out how to make it as simple as the fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

**position absolute**

Indicates that the element is absolutely positioned, while other elements are displayed on a web page like an absolutely positioned element and no. The element's position is defined by the properties left, top, right and bottom, also affects the position of the value of the position of the parent element. For example, if the parent is set to position value static or there is no parent, then the count is conducted from the edge coordinates of the browser window. If a parent is set to position value fixed, relative or absolute, then the count is conducted from the edge coordinates of the parent element.

I think this is the right way, as your case positioning vyschitvaetsya from the borders of the screen and in my example from the boundaries of the parent unit

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dxrel)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="thing">x</div>
</div>

.wrap {
   background: url('http://cl.ly/image/3j2s1u2n0t15/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-23%20at%2012.25.02.png') top center no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.thing {
            position: absolute;
            top: 45%;
            left: 45%;
        }
```